# Rails routing upon validation failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, routes

I have the following routes defined for my app:

```
  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  resources :users
```

Both work fine, but if I go to /signup, purposefully don't fill in the form (so that validation errors kick in), I am presented with the form (and errors), but the URL is now /users. I have tried adding ", :except => [:new]" to my :users resource, but that didn't help.

My users controller is:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = 'Sign Up'
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome to To Horse!'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = 'Sign Up'
      @user.password = nil
      @user.password_confirmation = nil
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really basic, but can't think what. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, as I'm fairly new to rails myself... But I believe that instead of "render 'new'" you should probably redirect back to the new url with whatever alert/flash you want to use.

Comment: That works as far as getting the URL right, but redirect nixes any parameters it has, including validation errors, so the form doesn't give any feedback anymore.